TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attribute')
For some reason, my application does not recognize one of the attributes of the received JSON. It receives 'posts' and should form links based on 'posts.links'.
I have written this code:
<Link
 v-for="link in props.posts.links"
 :key="link.label"
 v-if="link.url"
 :href="link.url"
 class="px-4 py-2 rounded"
 :class="{'bg-emerald-400 text-white': link.active, 'bg-gray-200': !link.active}"
  >
  {{ link.label }}
</Link>

But I get an error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

If you write with a hardcoded value (for example, posts.links\[0\].url), then the application recognizes the url attribute and everything works fine.
If you replace v-if="link.url" with v-if="link !== undefined", then another error appears:

[Vue warn]: Property "link" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

and the page loads, but the page navigation bar does not appear

Could you share the code for assigning value to posts.links?  The issue might be related to how the value is assigned to posts.links, potentially not following Vue's reactivity system correctly.

At the first rendering the posts.links is not available try to add a conditional rendering to check if it's available :
<template>
 <!-- ...-->
  <template v-if="posts.links">
   <Link
    v-for="link in posts.links"
    :key="link.label"
    :href="link.url"
     class="px-4 py-2 rounded"
     :class="{'bg-emerald-400 text-white': link.active, 'bg-gray-200': !link.active}"
  >
       {{ link.label }}
   </Link>

</template>

<!-- ...-->
</template>

Notice that you should not set v-if and v-for on the same element, also you don't need to reference props in template.

It can also be used in this way:
v-for-on-template

<template>
    <template v-for="link in props.posts.links" :key="link.label">
        <Link
         v-if="link.url"
         class="px-4 py-2 rounded"
         :href="link.url"
         :class="{'bg-emerald-400 text-white': link.active, 'bg-gray-200': !link.active}"
        >
           {{ link.label }}
        </Link>
    </template>
</template>


